# Why is this the window object in a jQuery event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrow-functions

I have a small on load script to set some classes that looks like this:

```
function frameIt() {
  console.log("called frameit")
  $( 'img' ).on('load', () => {
    console.log("running listener")
    debugger;
    $( this ).addClass( "tasty" );
  });
  console.log("set listener")
}
```

My issue is that `$(this)` is always set to the `window` even though `this` in the context is the loaded `img` tag as Chrome's debugger shows. Any ideas for why this is happening? Here's a Chrome debugger screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because arrow functions don't bind their own `this` context -- they take the `this` value of the enclosing scope. Since jQuery binds an event handler's `this` internally, but `this` cannot be bound to an arrow function, `this` refers to `window` as it is the `this` value of the enclosing scope. Use a regular function instead.

Comment: But... but... `() =>` is the new `function`!!?!

Comment: Apparently not. thanks for pointing this out. It want's me to wait 7 min till I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$( 'img' ).on('load', function () {
    console.log("running listener")
    debugger;
    $( this ).addClass( "tasty" );
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!